# ASP.NEt MVC 3 P1 Dependency Injection to Filters

Tags: dependency-injection, action-filter, asp.net-mvc-3

I have read through Brad Wilson's series of "ASP.NET MVC 3 Service Location" (http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html) and tried to get the DI work with Unity, but it would not (System.NullReferenceException). Have searched everywhere but can find nothing that takes up the subject. So, how do I resolve it with the DI and Action Filters?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: What code throws the exception?

Comment: Can you share your code and also show the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException comes when I try to call something from a interface. Everything is registered as it should and it works when I call the same thing from a controller.
Code: http://www.aspkoll.se/code/Index.asp?id=626 (error comes on line 9.
Stack Trace: http://www.aspkoll.se/code/Index.asp?id=625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was as it should be. The answer can be found here http://forums.asp.net/t/1598945.aspx